# TypeError in python function (int object not subscriptable)

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have a function that prints out 2x2 matrix convolutions of a 3x3 matrix:

```
image = [[1,0,1],       # Original image
        [0,1,0],
        [1,0,1]]
```

Where my function should print out:

```
[1,0]
[0,1]
[0,1]
[1,0]
[0,1]
[1,0]
[1,0]
[0,1]
```

The function is as follows

```
def convolution(image,result):
    # Image being 2d matrix
    # Result being return stacked 2d matrices
    # DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES
    a = 0   # Slice [a:b]
    b = 2
    r = 0
    # For row in image:
    for row in image:
        # While b < row length:
        while b < len(row):
            print(row[r][a:b])   # HERE IS THE ERROR
            print(row[r+1][a:b])
            a += 1
            b += 1
        a = 0   # Slice [a:b]
        b = 2
        matrix2d.clear()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conv.py", line 49, in <module>
    convolution(image,result3d)
  File "conv.py", line 24, in convolution
    print(row[r][a:b])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

The error message is for me relatively ambiguous. What can be done to correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `row` is a row of your image, for example `[1,0,1]` for the first row. Then in your `while` loop, `row[r]` is an integer, not an array.

The error message gives you the line of the error, and says that you cannot take the subscript of an integer, meaning that you cannot do `a[1]` if `a` is an `int`. With this information you have a good clue to find out that `row[r]` is indeed an integer.